# How to use Java encrypt Json by HmacSHA256

Tags: java, json, hmac

I have such a Json :

```
{
    "idcardno":"510525198803154232",
    "name":"丁品"
}
```

If I use HmacSHA256 encrypt it with key

```
252c04cdb0d047f8ab9a1eb49b1db1686e321104756ff792779a4d40d94f0dfd70a8b9ffa6d6d930e57d0e7206d26d13
```

**Then I should get such result:**

```
cd1fe72697a832d57198b8c0d00289309dffe6f05750aa2a145f9359e41f1843
```

I need to encrypt this json object in java environemnt, so I use below java code to achieve this:

```
import javax.crypto.Mac;
import javax.crypto.spec.SecretKeySpec;

import org.apache.commons.codec.binary.Base64;
import org.json.JSONObject;

public class EncryptUtil {

    // Charset to use when encrypting a string.
    private static final String UTF_8 = "UTF-8";
    // Encrypt key
    private static final String APP_SECRET = "252c04cdb0d047f8ab9a1eb49b1db1686e321104756ff792779a4d40d94f0dfd70a8b9ffa6d6d930e57d0e7206d";

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {   
        //build json object
        JSONObject object = new JSONObject();
        object.put("idcardno", "510525198803154232");
        object.put("name", "丁品");

        String result = enCode(object.toString());
        //print encrpted result
        System.out.println(result);
    }

    public static String enCode(String orginalMsg) throws Exception {
        try {   
            Mac sha256_HMAC = Mac.getInstance("HmacSHA256");
            SecretKeySpec secret_key = new SecretKeySpec(APP_SECRET.getBytes(), "HmacSHA256");
            sha256_HMAC.init(secret_key);
            String hash = Base64.encodeBase64String(sha256_HMAC.doFinal(orginalMsg.getBytes(UTF_8)));
            return hash;
        }
        catch (Exception e){
            throw new Exception(e);
        }
    }
}
```

**But the encypted result is :**

```
i2hF1WyxmS9MctkFLxBM2mgXeicraH9DhR9P9JySDFk=
```

How can get the correct result by Java code?

Comment: My first guess is: what you want to get is hex-encoded, but what you actually get is base64-encoded (because that's what you're doing in your code). In the last step, try using hex-encoding instead of base64-encoding.

Comment: @Jesper, thanks, I tried to use hex-encoded, it works, but it seems another reason is my json object has tab space

Comment: The developer who made the api has removed the limitation of tab format, so the problem was solved. Jesper's advice is useful!